# How to get multiple public ip address in India?

Tags: ip-address

We thought of having a VAS server at home and collected everything every bit of hardware but the problem we found is that how to get a subnet at cheaper price like that of digital ocean or any other server, how do they actually get IPs?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the same world over. You have to purchase a network connection from a telco that is willing to supply a subnet of IP addresses or a single IP address. Most are not willing to supply more than one IP address without a commercial connection with an SLA (service level agreement) and a hefty price tag. Otherwise, many broadband providers will provide a single IP address for a moderate price over the standard subscriber fee. You should be able to host almost anything you want behind a single IP address giving that your firewall or proxy will allow it. Generally, these cost more.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but if it can be used with hostnames instead of IPs, you could use http://www.noip.com/ to get a free Dynamic DNS address, and install the client on your network so that the hostname always has your current IP address.

That way, even with a dynamic IP address, you could always reach it by hostname.